# Postfix: forced reverse lookup for incoming connections

Tags: postfix, centos7, reverse-dns

I see following *maillog* records when new mail comes to server

```
connect from unknown [209.85.223.195]
client=unknown[209.85.223.195]
```

But that IP address is GMail IP and it has valid PTR-record which points to *mail-io0-f195.google.com*
My main.cf is [here](https://pastebin.com/eyGUeN2U)

**resolv.conf** content for Postfix listed below

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  nameserver 8.8.4.4
  nameserver [hosting_dns_servers_here]
 # NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.
 # The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.
   nameserver 1.1.1.1
   nameserver 1.0.0.1
   nameserver 77.88.8.8
   nameserver 77.88.8.1
```

So, how can I force Postfix to make reverse lookup and logs a domain name of mailserver not IP address?
I'm running CentOS 7.4

**P.S.** Postix "chained" in chroot

Comment: You should pick one set of DNS servers and use them exclusively. Mixing up between Google's, CloudFlare's and Yandex's DNS servers, and even the ones from your hosting provider, means that you can't tell where the problem is coming from.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I had already tried this, but there is no effect.
Is  postfix in general  can send reverse lookup query by it design?

Comment: Yes, Postfix can do this. I tested this on Debian Wheezy, but with different config. So, I'm digging to direction of DNS configuration and _smtp_host_lookup_  parametr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by Postfix in chroot mode.
Almost the same problem was [described](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38106/using-dns-lookup-in-chroot-postfix) earlier for Ubuntu.

You need to copy libraries needed for reverse lookup name resolution inside the chroot, e.g.

```
sudo cp -vl /usr/lib64/libnss_* /var/spool/postfix/lib64
```

Comment: As this solution is **only for chroot** environments, I reordered your answer a bit, if you don't mind. This way it might be more useful for others in the future. +1 for a good self-answer.

Comment: OK, thanks! There is no problem about your correction.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `smtp_host_lookup` to `dns` instead of your current `dns,native`. I'd like to refer you to [the manual](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_host_lookup) for further information.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it doesn't work.
I've just check your suggestion.

Comment: What does it tell you know @Twissell ?

Comment: There is no new messages and no changes.
 Just _unknown_ and IP was written in the log.
I guess it's some kind of internal issue of my VDS provider